# Trouble Getting Depth Testing To Work With Apple's Metal Graphics API

Tags: macos, 3d, metal

I'm spending some time in the evenings trying to learn Apple's Metal graphics API. I've run into a frustrating problem and so must be missing something pretty fundamental: I can only get rendered objects to appear on screen when depth testing is disabled, or when the depth function is changed to "Greater". What could possibly be going wrong? Also, what kinds of things can I check in order to debug this problem?

Here's what I'm doing:

1) I'm using SDL to create my window. When setting up Metal, I manually create a CAMetalLayer and insert it into the layer hierarchy. To be clear, I am not using MTKView and I don't want to use MTKView. Staying away from Objective-C and Cocoa as much as possible seems to be the best strategy for writing this application to be cross-platform. The intention is to write in platform-agnostic C++ code with SDL and a rendering engine which can be swapped at run-time. Behind this interface is where all Apple-specific code will live. However, I strongly suspect that part of what's going wrong is something to do with setting up the layer:

```
SDL_SysWMinfo windowManagerInfo;
SDL_VERSION(&windowManagerInfo.version);
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(&window, &windowManagerInfo);

// Create a metal layer and add it to the view that SDL created.
NSView *sdlView = windowManagerInfo.info.cocoa.window.contentView;
sdlView.wantsLayer = YES;
CALayer *sdlLayer = sdlView.layer;

CGFloat contentsScale = sdlLayer.contentsScale;
NSSize layerSize = sdlLayer.frame.size;

_metalLayer = [[CAMetalLayer layer] retain];
_metalLayer.contentsScale = contentsScale;
_metalLayer.drawableSize = NSMakeSize(layerSize.width * contentsScale,
                                     layerSize.height * contentsScale);
_metalLayer.device = device;
_metalLayer.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
_metalLayer.frame = sdlLayer.frame;
_metalLayer.framebufferOnly = true;

[sdlLayer addSublayer:_metalLayer];
```

2) I create a depth texture to use as a depth buffer. My understanding is that this step is necessary in Metal. Though, in OpenGL, the framework creates a depth buffer for me quite automatically:

```
CGSize drawableSize = _metalLayer.drawableSize;
MTLTextureDescriptor *descriptor =
[MTLTextureDescriptorr texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatDepth32Float_Stencil8 width:drawableSize.width height:drawableSize.height mipmapped:NO];
descriptor.storageMode = MTLStorageModePrivate;
descriptor.usage = MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget;
_depthTexture = [_metalLayer.device newTextureWithDescriptor:descriptor];
_depthTexture.label = @"DepthStencil";
```

3) I create a depth-stencil state object which will be set at render time:

```
MTLDepthStencilDescriptor *depthDescriptor = [[MTLDepthStencilDescriptor alloc] init];
depthDescriptor.depthWriteEnabled = YES;
depthDescriptor.depthCompareFunction = MTLCompareFunctionLess;
_depthState = [device newDepthStencilStateWithDescriptor:depthDescriptor];
```

4) When creating my render pass object, I explicitly attach the depth texture:

```
_metalRenderPassDesc = [[MTLRenderPassDescriptor renderPassDescriptor] retain];

MTLRenderPassColorAttachmentDescriptor *colorAttachment = _metalRenderPassDesc.colorAttachments[0];
colorAttachment.texture = _drawable.texture;
colorAttachment.clearColor  = MTLClearColorMake(0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 1.0);
colorAttachment.storeAction = MTLStoreActionStore;
colorAttachment.loadAction  = desc.clear ? MTLLoadActionClear : MTLLoadActionLoad;

MTLRenderPassDepthAttachmentDescriptor *depthAttachment = _metalRenderPassDesc.depthAttachment;
depthAttachment.texture = depthTexture;
depthAttachment.clearDepth = 1.0;
depthAttachment.storeAction = MTLStoreActionDontCare;
depthAttachment.loadAction = desc.clear ? MTLLoadActionClear : MTLLoadActionLoad;

MTLRenderPassStencilAttachmentDescriptor *stencilAttachment = _metalRenderPassDesc.stencilAttachment;
stencilAttachment.texture = depthAttachment.texture;
stencilAttachment.storeAction = MTLStoreActionDontCare;
stencilAttachment.loadAction = desc.clear ? MTLLoadActionClear : MTLLoadActionLoad;
```

5) Finally, at render time, I set the depth-stencil object before drawing my object:

```
[_encoder setDepthStencilState:_depthState];
```

Note that if I go into step 3 and change depthCompareFunction to MTLCompareFunctionAlways or MTLCompareFunctionGreater then I see polygons on the screen, but ordering is (expectedly) incorrect. If I leave depthCompareFunction set to MTLCompareFunctionLess then I see nothing but the background color. It acts AS IF all fragments fail the depth test at all times.

The Metal API validator reports no errors and has no warnings...

I've tried a variety of combinations of settings for things like the depth-stencil texture format and have not made any forward progress. Honestly, I'm not sure what to try next.

EDIT: GPU Frame Capture in Xcode displays a green outline of my polygons, but none of those fragments are actually drawn.

EDIT 2: I've learned that the Metal API validator has an "Extended" mode. When this is enabled, I get these two warnings:

```
warning: Texture Usage Should not be Flagged as MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget: This texture is not a render target. Clear the MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget bit flag in the texture usage options. Texture = DepthStencil. Texture is used in the  Depth attachment.

warning: Resource Storage Mode Should be MTLStorageModePrivate and it Should be Initialized with a Blit: This resource is rarely accessed by the CPU. Changing the storage mode to MTLStorageModePrivate and initializing it with a blit from a shared buffer may improve performance. Texture = 0x102095000.
```

When I head these two warnings, I get these two errors. (The warnings and errors seem to contradict one another.)]

```
error 'MTLTextureDescriptor: Depth, Stencil, DepthStencil, and Multisample textures must be allocated with the MTLResourceStorageModePrivate resource option.'

failed assertion `MTLTextureDescriptor: Depth, Stencil, DepthStencil, and Multisample textures must be allocated with the MTLResourceStorageModePrivate resource option.'
```

EDIT 3: When I run a sample Metal app and use the GPU frame capture tool then I see a gray scale representation of the depth buffer and the rendered object is clearly visible. This doesn't happen for my app. There, the GPU frame capture tool always shows my depth buffer as a plain white image.

Answer (score 12):

Okay, I figured this out. I'm going to post the answer here to help the next guy. There was no problem writing to the depth buffer. This explains why spending time mucking with depth texture and depth-stencil-state settings was getting me nowhere.

The problem is differences in the coordinate systems used for Normalized Device Coordinates in Metal versus OpenGL. In Metal, NDC are in the space [-1,+1]x[-1,+1]x[0,1]. In OpenGL, NDC are [-1,+1]x[-1,+1]x[-1,+1]. If I simply take the projection matrix produced by glm::perspective and shove it through Metal then results will not be as expected. In order to compensate for the NDC space differences when rendering with Metal, that projection matrix must be left-multiplied by a scaling matrix with (1, 1, 0.5, 1) on the diagonal.

I found these links to be helpful:
1. http://blog.athenstean.com/post/135771439196/from-opengl-to-metal-the-projection-matrix
2. http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html

EDIT: Replaced explanation with a more complete and accurate explanation. Replace solution with a better solution.

Comment: Looks like the first link is broken. Here is a new one. https://metashapes.com/blog/opengl-metal-projection-matrix-problem/