# How to use Depth Testing with CAMetalLayer using Metal and Swift?

Tags: swift, metal, depth-testing

Recently I decided to learn how to use the Metal framework with Swift. I read some turorials, watched videos, did a few things and finally I got to part where I have to use Depth Testing to make things look good.

I haven't done such low level graphics programming before, so I looked around the whole Internet on how Depth Testing works and how to implemented it using CAMetalLayer and Metal.

However all examples of Depth Testing, which I found, were done using Open GL and I couldn't find such functions in Metal.

How do I implement Depth Testing with CAMetalLayer using Metal and Swift?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This is a good example.
http://metalbyexample.com/up-and-running-3/

The key is that `CAMetalLayer` does not maintain the depth map for you. You need to create and manage explicitly the depth texture. And attach the depth texture to the depth-stencil descriptor which you use to create the render-encoder.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create the depth texture from a pass?

Answer (score 1):

The question of [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637659/trouble-getting-depth-testing-to-work-with-apples-metal-graphics-api) contains your answer, although it's written in Obj-C. But basically, like what Dong Feng has pointed out, you need to create and manage the depth texture by yourself.

Here's a Swift 4 snippet for how to create a depth texture

```swift
func buildDepthTexture(_ device: MTLDevice, _ size: CGSize) -> MTLTexture {
    let desc = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(
        pixelFormat: .depth32Float_stencil8,
        width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height), mipmapped: false)
    desc.storageMode = .private
    desc.usage = .renderTarget
    return device.makeTexture(descriptor: desc)!
}
```

And here's how you need to attach it to a `MTLRenderPassDescriptor`

```swift
let renderPassDesc = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()

let depthAttachment = renderPassDesc.depthAttachment!
// depthTexture is created using the above function
depthAttachment.texture = depthTexture
depthAttachment.clearDepth = 1.0
depthAttachment.storeAction = .dontCare

// Maybe set up color attachment, etc.
```